# Sort and update state at the same time React useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I want to add a value to an array(update its state) its working fine but the item is added to the end of the array. I am trying to call sort() method immediately after updating state. Is there a better method to update the state an sort at the same time.

```
  const UpdateZoom = (scale:number)=>{
if(scale>0)
{
  setzoomFactors(zoomFactors =>
     [...zoomFactors, scale]);
}
```

}

Setting state immediately after like below resets the state

```
      setzoomFactors(zoomFactors => zoomFactors.sort())
```

Is there any way to add and sort at the state at the same time

Comment: sort mutates array, you probably should copy it first or just do `setzoomFactors(zoomFactors =>
     [...zoomFactors, scale].sort()`

Answer (score 2):

How about setting state after sorting?

```
const newArray = [...originArray, element];

newArray.sort();

setState(newArray);
```